# Toggle Play/Pause Youtube Video with external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, fullpage.js

I have a template I'm building out using fullPage js to create sliding sections. The page supports video, but scroll and gestures are disabled when users scroll with the cursor on top of the video itself. Likewise, this behavior is observed on mobile.

To work around this, I'm using an empty div overlaying the youtube iframe. This solves the scrolling behavior, but I also lack the ability to directly control the youtube player. I've tried using the youtube API and jquery to fake being able to toggle play/pause with the empty div I have on top of the youtube player, but it's not working.

http://codepen.io/lumpeter/pen/XpayeB

The primary code for youtube is:

```
 function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("player");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
        $('#video-button').click(function(event){
            ytplayer.playVideo();
        });
    }

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        $('#video-button').click(function(event){
            ytplayer.pauseVideo();
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#video-button').click(function(event){
            ytplayer.playVideo();
        });
    } 
}
```

Can anybody tell why this isn't working? I have event listeners looking for changes and using a boolean to detect the state of the video to toggle play/pause, but for some reason this doesn't work like I anticipated.

===============UPDATE=================

I've also tried the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pauseVideo', function(){  
player = new YT.Player('myVideo')             
if (event.data == player.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
      $('#myVideo').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}','*');
}

if (event.data == player.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      $('#myVideo').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}','*');

    }

});
```

However, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

As fullpage.js already does part of the job by adding `?enablejsapi=1` and loading the JS script of the API for you, then you only have to do this:

```
var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('myVideo');
}

$(document).on('click', '#pauseVideo', function(){                       
      $('#myVideo').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}','*');
});
```

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1691/)

Comment: This works great! However I'm trying to toggle pause or play, so this would require being able to detect the state of the video.

Comment: I have tried the following : var is_playing = false;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseVideo");
  var that = this;
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function(click_event) {
    if (that.is_playing) {
        player.pauseVideo();    
    }else {
        player.playVideo();
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    this.is_playing = true;
  }
}

Comment: Just deal with the state of the video in a javascript variable. Assume it will be playing after section load and whenever you detect the click, change the state. Easy.

Comment: By the way, you are missing the `event` param in your click event on your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alvaro! Yeah I was overthinking the solution a bit with the youtube api. I just needed to use a boolean with a binary true/false statement. Super easy, should have seen it before. Again thanks for your help!

```
var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('myVideo',{
          events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });
}

var isPlaying = true;



$(document).on('click', '#pauseVideo', function(){    
    if ( isPlaying == true){
      $('#myVideo').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}','*');
      isPlaying = false;
    } else {
      $('#myVideo').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}','*');
      isPlaying = true;
    }          
});
```